# How to collect data of other apps using Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, data-collection

**Example 1 - Instagram**

Let's say that our app has a text field which ask for a Instagram username, and when someone submits our app displays the followers and following count.

```
 input(textfield): teddysphotos
 output          : 35.4M followers 2 following
```

like such

**Example 2 - Snapchat**

Another example where we add the snapchat username and our app displays the Snap Streak number with our friend.

How can we collect such data using an app?

Comment: You should look into the social media platform dev api. You can create an auth token  for the users account that you can use to extract the data you may need. Bear in mind though with all the new privacy policies, its pretty limited what you can get the user to allow access to. See this for [instagram](https://www.instagram.com/developer/). Then use flutter to access the api... simple!

Comment: @user15076841 Api's are restricted to collect some data right? Is there some thing like selenium in python, for flutter?